# update modelobject in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-controller

I am trying to update user in my model object

```
   public ActionResult AddJob(JobQueue job,HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       job.User = "itdev";

       TryUpdateModel(job) 

       if (ModelState.IsValid)//Always returns false
       {

       }
    }
```

MODEL

```
   public class JobQueue { 
   [Required] 
   [Display(Name="JobId")] 
   public string JobId { get; set; } 

   [Required] [Display(Name = "FileName")] 
   public string FileName { get; set; } 

   [Required] 
   [Display(Name = "Job Run Date")] 
   public DateTime JobRunDate { get; set; } 

   [Required] 
   [Display(Name = "Email")] 
   public string Mail { get; set; } 

   [Required] 
   [Display(Name = "User")] 
   public string User { get; set; }
```

I tried using TryUpdateModel(job) and UpdateModel(job) after assigning the values.Both of these does not seem to update the model because ModelState.IsValid return false.Can someone point me in the right directions?I am using MVC3

Thanks,

Sab

Comment: Is the type for `User` a string?  If not, the string being assigned wouldn't be valid. . .  Can you show us your User class?

Comment: Yes user is a string in JobQueue class.The idea is to assign user from the controller using User.Identity.Name but I am hardcoding it for testing at the moment.

Comment: The next step seems to be to try what Gaz Winter suggested below and remove `TryUpdateModel(job)` as, in this context, it doesn't seem necessary.  If the ModelState.IsValid says it is invalid, then we need to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong here, but I think `job.User = "itdev";` should be sufficent to update the model without using the `TryUpdateModel(job)` thats how we do it in our site anyway. I have never need to use any method to actually update the model itself. Just assigned values manually.

It depends on how your model is setup I  guess.

You should probably post the code for your model just in case my answer isnt helpful.

Comment: yes i would have thought so.After assign the values the job object does contain the values but ModelState.IsValid returns false.

Comment: User string in my model class is         [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User")]
        public string User { get; set; }

Comment: When you debug it, are all of your models fields populated? If there are any missing then that would cause it to be invalid!

Comment: When the debugger hits the first line the required data user is not populated.I manually assign the value job.User = "itdev";After this the job object contains the required value.I can get round the issue by doing ModelState["User"].Errors.Clear(); but not sure if this is a proper approach.

Comment: If you are always going to assign the value inside the controller rather than from a webpage. I am not sure you need the required field. So you could remove that all together.

Comment: I am actually thinking on those lines of removing the required attribute.

Comment: Thats what i would do, but I am pretty new to MVC myself, I am sure there are probably some guru's out there that would advise against it :)

Comment: All I did was removed the required field attribute.Not sure if thats the right approach though

Comment: OK. I think its an ok option thats why i suggested it.